# Нужно ли указывать каноническую ссылку?

Tags: seo

Имеется страница, например: https://site.ru/page/name-page 
Нужно ли в head этой страницы прописывать:?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://site.ru/page/name-page" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я хотел бы дополнить ответ от Baklazhko. В том же самое руководстве Гугл, которое сообщено в ответе Baklazhko, Гугл информирует нас:

> Для чего выбирать канонический URL?
>
> Указывать каноническую страницу из числа одинаковых или похожих стоит
> в следующих случаях:
>
> Если нужно выбрать, какой URL следует показывать в результатах поиска.

Канонический мета-тег - это способ сообщить поисковым системам, что конкретный URL-адрес представляет собой главную копию страницы. На практике канонический тег сообщает поисковым системам, какую версию URL вы хотите отобразить в результатах поиска.

Answer (score 2):

Да.

Это поможет устранить попадания возможных дублей, копий в индекс ПС. Позволит не растрачивать краулинговый бюджет на сканирование дублей.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru